# Value of UITextField in Custom Table view cell changes while scrolling up and scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the `UITableviewCell` to create the profile form in my application project. So for this I am using a single cell. The custom cell consists of the `UITextField`. Initially these fields are populated with the web service.

[image: Initial form details]

Now I can edit the full name as shown below:

[image]

You can see I have typed raul in the full name field.

But if I scroll the table view upwards and scroll down back, I lose my changed value and it shows the old entry in the first text field.

I am using the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let regCell = profileManagement.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"regFirstCell", for: indexPath)as? RegistrationFieldTableViewCell
    regCell?.registrationField.tag = indexPath.row
    regCell?.registrationFieldImage.image = fieldImages[indexPath.row]
    let nameFields = NSLocalizedString( regFieldsNames[indexPath.row], comment: "")
    regCell?.registrationField.placeholder = nameFields
    regCell?.registrationField.autocorrectionType = .no
    regCell?.registrationField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    regCell?.showPassword.isHidden = true
    //Swith case for giving keypad to textfields
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.name
    case 1:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.emailId
    case 2:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.civilId
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    case 3:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.phoneNumber
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    case 4:
      regCell?.registrationField.isSecureTextEntry = true
      regCell?.registrationField.text = "abhijith123"
      regCell?.showPassword.isHidden = true
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    default:
      print("Something else")
    }
    return regCell!
}
```

Comment: When you type a new value, what code do you use for saving it?

Comment: currently i am not using any code to store the new value. please suggest this how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it. Every time we see row 0, you are saying:

```
  regCell?.registrationField.text = self.name
```

But you never *change* `self.name` to what the user types in the field. So naturally when we show row 0 again, it reverts to the old `self.name`.

Comment: Yes off course. So please suggest what to do when we edit the values in text field

Comment: Make yourself the text field's action target so that you get `editingChanged` control events. Or be the text field's delegate so that you get `textFieldDidEndEditing`. When you get an event, read the text field's value and store it in the appropriate place. Example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p447editInsertAndRearrangeRows/ch21p741editInsertAndRearrangeRows/RootViewController.swift

Comment: i can see the code for editingChanged. Is that the only thing which we need to use?

Comment: Just try it! I've explained the principle; I've shown you a complete working downloadable example; I'm not going to write your code for you as well. You seem to think SO is your personal servant.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to cell reusability.

You need to save your changes in order to bring them up the next time you view the cell. Currently what you are doing is you are changing the text, swiping away (the cell is reused). then swiping back (the cell is reloaded with the cellForRowAt function, thus the value of it is set)

What you need to do is to actually store the values the user is inserting so that when the user scrolls away then back again, we display the saved value.

To do so, store your values in an array, and in  let `yourlabel.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]`

So assuming you have a tableview with 3 rows, each row have a textview.

1- Define an array: `valuesArray = ["", "", ""]`

2- set `textField.tag = indexPath.row` in the cellAtIndex function

3- set `textField.text = valuesArray[indexPath.row]` in the cellAtIndex function as well

4- In you didEndEditing Delegate for the textField, set this: `valuesArray[textField.tag] = textField.text`

And this should work

Hope this helps!

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani please do insert the code in your answer to store the values which the user is inserting

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani but at cell at index function i already have values being set from webservice.

Comment: can you store all the values in the array before loading the table?